# Binding this[], где индекс это статическое свойство

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть пару классов

```
public class A
{
  public static A A1 = new A();
  public static A A2 = new A();
  public static A A3 = new A();
  ...
}


public class B
{
  public string this[A a] { get { return a.ToString(); /*тут может быть что угодно*/ } }
}
```

Необходимо указать в биндинге элемента, с `DataContext` экземпляра класса `B`, к свойству `.[A:A1]`, что-то вроде этого:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.[MyEnum:A.A1]">
```

однако возникает ошибка биндинга

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''B' (HashCode=36232091)'. BindingExpression:Path=.[MyEnum:A.A1]; DataItem='B' (HashCode=36232091); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

но если мы делаем

```
public class B
{
  public string this[int a] { get { return a.ToString(); } }
}
```

и

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.[666]">
```

то все проходит на ура. Как сделать биндинг к перечисляемому свойству по индексу статического свойства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не так уж прост. На самом деле, проблема в том, как получить типизированное значение вместо `MyEnum:A.A1` (этот текст XAML считает просто строкой). Простое решение с `x:Static`:

```
Text="{Binding Path=.[{x:Static MyEnum:A.A1}]"
```

не проходит: судя по всему, markup extension'ы не распознаются внутри аргумента `Path`.

Но есть несложный обходной путь. Поскольку ваш индекс — константа, то и следить за его изменениями не нужно. А значит, можно просто привязаться через конвертер.

Пишем:

```
public class IndexerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            return value;

        // мы не знаем точный тип - значит, вызываем через рефлексию
        return value.GetType()
                    .GetMethod("get_Item") // так "внутри" называется indexer
                    .Invoke(value, new object[] { parameter });
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Теперь XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MyEnum="clr-namespace:..."
        ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <MyEnum:IndexerConverter x:Key="IndexerConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IndexerConverter},
                              ConverterParameter={x:Static MyEnum:A.A1}}"/>
</Window>
```

---

Альтернативное решение с более хитрым созданием `Path` можно найти [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371493/276994):

```
[ContentProperty("Parameters")]
public class PathConstructor : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IList Parameters { get; set; }

    public PathConstructor()
    {
        Parameters = new List<object>();
    }
    public PathConstructor(string path, object p0)
    {
        Path = path;
        Parameters = new[] { p0 };
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new PropertyPath(Path, Parameters.Cast<object>().ToArray());
    }
}
```

и XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={MyEnum:PathConstructor [(0)], {x:Static MyEnum:A.A1}}}"/>
```

Comment: ну с конвертерами у меня сделано (правда мультиконвертер). Просто не очень то и читабельно. Но Ваш вариант смотрится симпатично.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Мультиконвертер понадобится, если `MyEnum:A.A1` реально будет переменной (например, из другого `Binding`'а, или каким-нибудь свойством), а не константой.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Нашёл ещё одно решение, дописал ответ. Выглядит изящнее.